# Web server URL Redirection loop in web page

Tags: mod-rewrite

Thanks in advance

Am doing URL redirection in Web Server (httpd.conf ) trying to redirect a URL  from

RewriteRule ^/wps/(.*)/insurance/hospital-

cash-benefit    http://hostname/wps/$1/retail- banking/insurance/hospital- cash-benefit      [L,R=301]

When am trying to hit new URL with old one  am getting the bellow error in web browser "
This webpage has a redirect loop "

http://hostname/wps/portal/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/retail-banking/ retail-banking/insurance/ hospital-cash-benefit

the output is like this i don't know why am getting this loop error and  I cleared all caches history every thing in browser but still error exits.

Comment: It might be the formatting on the site, but I can't see your expected source and destination URLs.  Please can you supply those so that I can work out what the regex is doing.

Comment: I need an example of the actual source URL and the actual expected URL. Your rewrite rule matches both your old and your new URL which is why it is looping.  If you can show me an old URL and a new URL then I can make a rule to match the old but not the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking strictly to the "looping" problem. If I'm reading your RewriteRule correctly, then your substitution (target URI) looks like it will match against your pattern... and that would explain the loop. In this case, a common practice is to use a RewriteCond to ignore the substitution (target URI) when it comes back in. The one piece that seems unique to the substitution is the /retail-banking/ portion. So maybe try this:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+/retail-banking/

and that would need to go directly above your RewriteRule

UPDATED - Skip flag Example:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .+/retail-banking/
RewriteRule .? - [S=50]
RewriteRule 1
RewriteRule 2
...  ...
RewriteRule 50

Comment: To have a single RewriteCond apply to multiple RewriteRules, you have to negate (reverse) the RewriteCond and use a leading RewriteRule with the skip flag. This assumes all the RewriteRules you want the Condition to apply to are grouped together and immediately follow. I've edited my answer to include an example. The skip flag is documented here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s

Comment: @VinodKumarP, this has evolved a good bit from your original question and likely requires consulting outside the scope of this thread / forum. Its important that you take the time to understand how these examples work so that you can apply and tailor them to your own configuration (refer to documentation if needed). You stated previously that, if you added the Cond above "every URL which is not working then URL's are working". Using the skip option would effectively do the same thing. Make sure your RewriteRules are ordered so that only those needing the Cond applied are in the skip grouping

Comment: @VinodKumarP. Please submit your latest issue under a new question. This is the 4th problem you've asked about: 1. How to fix a Rewrite loop. 2. How to apply a RewriteCond to multiple Rules. 3. Page does not display properly using skip flag. 4. % encoding missing from Rewrite substitution. These are all good, but they need to be submitted as separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

So you are wanting to get from this URL:

hostname/wps/portal/insurance/hospital-cash-benefit

to this URL:

hostname/wps/portal/retail-banking/insurance/hospital-cash-benefit

They are basically the same except that your new one has an extra 'level' of "retail-banking".  The /(.*)/ is matching any character, including the "/" and other letters.  So it will match /portal/ and /portal/retail-banking and /portal/retail-banking/retail-banking which is why you are having the redirect loop.

Why not just put the whole URL in?  Why are you even putting in the wildcard search since it is so specific?  If you really to match the base URL for some reason, then rather specify the characters you are expecting and the number of levels you are expecting instead of the wildcard search, like this:

^/wps/([A-z0-9-]*)/insurance/hospital-cash-benefit

That will match all letter characters, all number characters and "-" characters but not "/".  The only other character you can throw in there that is valid in a URL is a "%" but you most likely won't need that unless you have some strange characters that need to be escaped.  That pattern is only expecting one level between /wps/ and /insurance/ so it won't match the new URL.  Try it out and if you are struggling with the pattern because you have other URLs to redirect, try [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/), turn on multiline and then you can paste in a number of URLs and make sure that only the ones you want to have matching match.

Comment: so the rule you entered was 
^/wps/([A-z0-9\-]*)/insurance/hospital-cash-benefit  http://hostname/wps/$1/retail- banking/insurance/hospital-cash-benefit
I see that when copying and pasting the one dash was not escaped